# How to interpolate alpha from CURRENT_ALPHA to TARGET_ALPHA for each pixel in shader language? (Godot/GLSL)

Tags: shader, glsl, fragment-shader, godot

I want to make "trails" of objects on my shader that appear and disappear gradually.

I am getting pixels (for fragment shader) where objects are from uniform texture.

Basically, I have my TARGET_ALPHA for alpha for this pixel.

How can I interpolate over time (1 second) current alpha for pixel to TARGET_ALPHA?

I can't understand how to achieve this.
I tried

```
ALPHA = mix(ALPHA, TARGET_ALPHA, 0.01); // mix is lerp in godot shader language
```

But it won't work like it's some kind of ordinary game engine code, because ALPHA won't retain it's value every call of shader function and value stays the same.

I assume something can be done with TIME but I don't understand what. I tried sin(TIME) etc, but it just makes value go up and down, and I want to achieve interpolation without it going back. So my ALPHA would just always follow TARGET_ALPHA with interpolation.